# Cannot distinguish depth in an isometric cube

Tags: java, isometric

I am having a problem with distinguishing different depths in my new 'game.'
It is a game similar to Minecraft, only it is rendering in isometric format. The problem is, I cannot think of a way to distinguish the different depths.
Screenshots:
Above Ground:
[image: Aboveground]
Under Ground:
[image: Underground]

In the last picture, the player is 2 tiles underground, but it seems as if it's only 1 tile underground.
I'm not sure if this is even possible or not, but if you can think of something, please share it!

Comment: Maybe highlight the squares that the player lines up to on the edges of the cube?

Comment: Is slightly changing the angle from which you view the world an option? Your problem arises because different blocks happen to line up perfectly from the current POV, so changing the pitch angle should help.

Comment: IMHO I don't see any problem. you can adjust the angle as Thomas suggested.

Comment: I did not want to change the POV in my game, since that would mean rewriting the engine and redoing the sprites completely. Instead, I  used Ben's suggestion and highlighted the tiles on the side of the cube that the player corresponds to.
This was the result:
http://imgur.com/5YEH1cr
The new problem is that when the player is underground and creates tunnels, they can get very confusing.
http://imgur.com/GLj3PZq

Comment: What you could do is make all the stuff in the way of the view of the cave even less visible, and highlight the ground level you're currently on. For greater clarification, you could apply a thicker outline to wherever there would be a wall or ledge.